# How to stop Memory Error in python for pdf conversion?

Tags: python, pdf, memory, memory-management, poppler

I'm currently using pdf2image - a poppler wrapper- to convert a pdf into pillow images so I can view the pdf. However, no matter what pdf I use, I always get this following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\karee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\lib\threading.py", line 954, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\karee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\lib\threading.py", line 892, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\karee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 1479, in _readerthread
    buffer.append(fh.read())
MemoryError
```

Is there any way to fix this short of changing the specs on my computer or getting a new one?
Here's my code:

```
root = Tk()
pdf_frame = Frame(root).pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
scrol_y = Scrollbar(pdf_frame, orient=VERTICAL)
pdf = Text(pdf_frame, yscrollcommand=scrol_y.set, bg="grey")
scrol_y.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
scrol_y.config(command=pdf.yview)
pdf.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
pages = convert_from_path('Books/Keeper Of The Lost Cities/Everblaze ( PDFDrive ).pdf', size=(800, 900),
                          poppler_path=r"poppler-21.03.0\Library\bin")
photos = []
for i in range(len(pages)):
    photos.append(ImageTk.PhotoImage(pages[i]))
for photo in photos:
    pdf.image_create(END, image=photo)

    pdf.insert(END, '\n\n')
mainloop()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How big is your ram? What's your ram usage like when you run this program? How big is the file in question?

Comment: @wxz I have 24GB of ram, I don't know what the ram usage is and the file is quite long a couple hundred pages

Comment: @KJ I want to create a PDF viewer in Python and the way I found to do this is using pdf2image and converting it to PIL images. Could you show me how to batch it into sets that I would do this for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just batch convert the PDF in batches of say 5 each time. i.e.,

```
from pdf2image import pdfinfo_from_path,convert_from_path
info = pdfinfo_from_path(pdf_file, userpw=None, poppler_path=None)

maxPages = info["Pages"]
for page in range(1, maxPages+1, 10) : 
   convert_from_path(pdf_file, dpi=200, first_page=page,
```